# Error installing mysql 5.5 FATAL ERROR: Could not find my_print_defaults

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I installed Mysql 5.5 using Homebrew, specifically Homebrew versions - https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions.  After the installation, I attempted to run the commands it suggests:

```
Set up databases to run AS YOUR USER ACCOUNT with:
    unset TMPDIR
    mysql_install_db --verbose --user=`whoami` --basedir="$(brew --prefix mysql)" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
...
```

However, the second line causes an error.  When I run:

```
mysql_install_db --verbose --user=`whoami` --basedir="$(brew --prefix mysql)" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
```

I get the following error:

FATAL ERROR: Could not find my_print_defaults

The following directories were searched:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.10/bin
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.10/extra
```

Perhaps this is because the script is by default searching for files in my old mysql 5.6 directory even though I ran "brew uninstall mysql" before doing this.

Still, if I specify the new mysql installation directory, I still get an error:

```
$ mysql_install_db --verbose --user=`whoami` --basedir="$/usr/local/Cellar/mysql55/5.5.30" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp

FATAL ERROR: Could not find my_print_defaults

The following directories were searched:

    $/usr/local/Cellar/mysql55/5.5.30/bin
    $/usr/local/Cellar/mysql55/5.5.30/extra
```

This is strange because the first directory indeed does contain my_print_defaults if I ls the directory.

Why, then, am I still getting this error?

Comment: I fixed this by uninstalling it with Homebrew and reinstalling it with a package - http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.5.html#downloads

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem.  Part of the problem is that your mysql_install_db line is incorrect. As I documented [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/issues/200#issuecomment-19707324), you have to perform the following steps - including one before running the mysql_install_db command - to avoid subsequent errors:

1. Change the name of `/usr/local/opt/mysql55/share/mysql55` to `/usr/local/opt/mysql55/share/mysql`
2. Run the following command (same as above with one variation in the --datadir argument):

   mysql_install_db --verbose --user=`whoami` --basedir="$(brew --prefix mysql55)" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql55 --tmpdir=/tmp

If you look at the output from when mysql is being installed it has datadir set to /usr/local/var/mysql55.

3. Rename /usr/local/opt/mysql55/share/mysql back to /usr/local/opt/mysql55/share/mysql55
4. Start the server

Step 3 is necessary because you get the "The server quit without updating PID file.." error when trying to start the mysql server, and the apache error log shows errors trying to find `/usr/local/opt/mysql55/share/mysql55/english/errmsg.sys`.